# Creating cordova 5.x android gradle build offline

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Recently I upgraded my Cordova project from Cordova 3.0 to 5.3.3 and Android platform from 3.6 to 4.1. New android platform uses gradle for build and need to connect to internet (maven repo) every day for building. Once it connects to repo, it does not require connection for that day.

I am working behind the proxy which does not have access to maven repo. I am new to gradle build and want to configure gradle for offline building cordova application.

Here are environment details

- OS -> MAC OSX
- Cordova version -> 5.3.3
- Cordova Android platform version -> 4.1

Kindly suggest.

Comment: does your build.gradle have a `repositories` section?

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies are declared in Gradle in the `dependencies` section and the `repositories` section controls where the dependencies are fetched from. For example:

```
repositories {
     jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
}
```

This says, guava:18.0 is fetched during compile time, from the [jcenter()](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) repository. You can also use maven central as:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

A custom repo like a company repo as:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2"
    }
}
```

or, the local `.m2` repo as:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
```

You can define multiple repositories as well:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}
```

Gradle searches for dependencies in the order that the repositories are listed. So it will look in local .m2 first, and if a matching dependency isn't available, it goes out to JCenter to download dependencies.

Comment: thanks for the details. Actually we do not have local maven repo, maybe I need to create one. Still is there any way where I can change the frequency of checking updates. Doesn't it works like when I build first time, it downloads the dependancies and when I change my dependancies or build file then only it tries to check for updates or changes.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the `--offline` flag.